# Not using '&' when passing a pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

"some_function" receives a pointer to a character - it's defined as follows:

```
void some_function(char *c);
```

From what I learned, when we want to call "some_function" - we should pass an to the argument using the '&' operator:

```
some_function(&some_char);
```

But I've seen working examples where "some_function" directly receives a string:

```
some_function("some string");
```

How does it work? Is this practice recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C all literal strings are really arrays of (read-only) characters, including the ending null-terminator.

And as all arrays in C, they can decay to a pointer to their first element.

Which means all string literals can be used whenever a `char *` is expected.

---

It's similar (but not equivalent) to having:

```
char some_string[] = "some string";
some_function(some_string);  // equal to some_string(&some_string[0])
```

Comment: Rather more like: `const char *some_string = "some string"; some_function(some_string);`. (in your code, `some_string` can be modified legally but isn't the case in OP's - string literal is directly passed).

Answer (score 0):

> From what I learned, when we want to call "some_function" - we should pass an to the argument using the `&` operator.

Note that in the case of arrays, you should omit the `&` operator since an array decays to a pointer to its first element when passed as argument to a function.

> But I've seen working examples where "some_function" directly receives a string:
>
> `some_function("some string");`
>
> How does it work? Is this practice recommended?

A *string literal* is basically stored in an not modifiable `char` array ([likely but not necessary in read-only memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/)).

When you use a string literal like that which is is indicated by its surrounding `"`s, it decays to a pointer to its first element, which is of  type `char *`.

So, There is no problem using this technique.

Note that you can't modify a string literal, so any attempt to change the contents of `"some string"` inside of `some_function invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In C strings are actually an array of characters. String can be declared like this:

```
// # 1
char *some_string = "some string";
// # 2
char some_string[] = "some string";
```

and passed to function like this:

```
some_function(&some_string[0]);
some_function(some_string);
// or if it's just string literal
some_function("some string");
```

All of them have `char *` type.

Comment: I think you should at least mention how your definitions #1 and #2 differ. One is a pointer and the other allocates space for the contents.